# Minimum and maximum data form Data Table

Tags: c#, datatable

I have data Table with four columns: `Date`, `isin`, `Price` and `State`.
I need to get minimum and maximum date from the `Date` column.
I'm using this code and it works fine with one file however with other file it shows me wrong maximum date.

```
 DateTime stDate = Convert.ToDateTime((excleTable.Compute("min(date)", string.Empty)));
 DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime((excleTable.Compute("max(date)", string.Empty)));
```

For example on first row i have `02/27/2015` and on last row i have `03/31/2015` but it reads only till `03/09/2015` which is incorrect.
Any ideas what should i do ?

Comment: What is the `DataType` of your columns ? looks like it is `string` and not `DateTime`

Comment: yes its string data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your column type isn't `DateTime`. If you can fix that than make sure that your `DataTable` has `DateTime` type for column `date`, otherwise you can use LINQ's `Max` and `Min` and convert your column to `DateTime` like:

```
DateTime stDate =  dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .Max(r => Convert.ToDateTime(r.Field<string>("date")));

DateTime eDate =  dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .Min(r => Convert.ToDateTime(r.Field<string>("date")));
```

You may have to use `DateTime.ParseExact` for converting to `DateTime`, if your string values doesn't correspond to default/available `DateTime` formats, like:

```
DateTime stDate =  dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Max(r => DateTime.ParseExact(r.Field<string>("date"), 
                                    "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: worked in my case i wonder why my two line of code were not working with one file any ways thanks

Comment: @Tahir, with string type, it will use the natural sort order and not the `DateTime` sort order you expected.